# Angular dropdown bounded to function is being infinitely called

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, binding, primeng

I am using a PrimeNg dropdown and passing its options using a function. However, it is being called infinite number of times. Will this cause an issue with the performance or any other factor, and if so, is there a workaround?

HTML:

```
<tabset>
    <tab *ngFor="let item of countries" [heading]="item.country">
        <div class="mb-5 col-md-6">
            <label for="state" class="col-lg-12 form-label">State</label>
            <p-dropdown [options]="getStates(item.countryId)" name="stateId" placeholder="Select State" optionLabel="name" optionValue="id" [showClear]="true"> </p-dropdown>
        </div>                           
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

TS:

```
    getStates(countryId: number): StateDto[] {
        console.log('getting states');
        return this.stateMap.filter(x => x.countryId == countryId)[0]?.states;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace  `[options]="getStates(item.countryId)"` with a pure pipe like `[options]="item.countryId | getStates".

Create a pipe, and add the logic for retrieve the stats inside.

Then, only if `item.countryId` change the method inside pure pipe is called.